# How to have 2 variables with 2 different seq - Bash Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, seq

I have this command that I want to use to pull information out of a Motorola Chassis. I will use SNMP V2 and Bash script to pull the information.

**2 Variables**

**IP** = last octet  of  Chassis IP  (1...10)
**Port#**= Chassis port ID  (10 10 240)

The command that I have is:

```
for ip in `seq 1 10`;
    do echo Chassis .$ip ; 
    snmpwalk -v2c -c ComunityName 172.27.253.$ip IF-MIB::ifAdminStatus.$port; 
    echo -e "\n";  
done
```

This command won't work because I have not declared yet the `$port` variable, but how can I integrate this variable in to the same line of commands in order for it to perform the `seq` 10 20 30 40 .... 240?

Comment: ever heard of nested loops ?

Comment: I was reading about nested loops but Im not able to properly setup the script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an inner loop for the `$port` values. As you're under Bash, you can use Bash sequence `{1..10}` instead of `seq`:

```
for ip in {1..10}; do 
  echo Chassis .$ip;
  for port in {10..240..10}; do
    echo snmpwalk -v2c -c ComunityName 172.27.253.$ip IF-MIB::ifAdminStatus.$port; echo -e "\n"; 
  done
done
```

Comment: The C-style loop is a better option, as it doesn't have to generate the full list of number up front: `for ((port=10; port<=240; port+=10))`, for example.

Comment: I have tried this but the output is not properly sort : command : #!/bin/bash
#Port status
for ip in {1..10}; do
  for port in {10..240..10}; do
    echo Chassis .$ip;
    snmpwalk -v2c -c comunitiName 172.27.253.$ip IF-MIB::ifAdminStatus.$port|awk '{print $1,$4}'|sed -e 's/'IF-MIB::ifAdminStatus.'//g';
  done
done  the output is : Chassis .1
10 up(1)
Chassis .1
20 up(1)
Chassis .1
30 up(1)
Chassis .1
40 up(1)
Chassis .1
 and the desire output is :Chassis .1
10 up(1)
20 up(1)
30 up(1)
40 up(1)......

Comment: I did it with you assistance I figured out I move it the echo chassis to the other loop Thank you

Comment: @Greyfox You're right. I moved the `echo Chassis .$ip` at the right place.